# what are the configuration in settings.py to send e-mail using Django from business outlook email (eg .. - office@test.com )

Tags: django, outlook, smtp

i have been trying to send email using this configuration

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp-mail.outlook.com' 
EMAIL_PORT = 25
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'office@test.com' 
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = '********' 
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_USE_SSL = False
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'office@test.com'
```

but I am getting error saying that

```
OSError at /product_detail/test/
[Errno 101] Network is unreachable
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe this should work

```py
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.office365.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = '<outlook email>' 
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = '<your outlook email password>' 
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_USE_SSL = False
```

You should also enable sending mails via smtp from your outlook account settings.
For further reference you can look into the official documentation of outlook

[SMTP Documentation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/pop-imap-and-smtp-settings-for-outlook-com-d088b986-291d-42b8-9564-9c414e2aa040)

Comment: thank you for responding , but it did not work . this time it is showing (535, b'5.7.3 Authentication unsuccessful [MA1PR0101CA0031.INDPRD01.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM]')